# How to get AWS Lambda to trigger when an EBS snapshot completes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm creating bunch of EBS snapshots as part of AWS Lambda.  I need to capture events when these snapshots complete so I can create an ec2 instance based on these.

I could use [snapshot waiter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#snapshotCompleted-waiter) but this polls and sometimes snapshot creation can take long time.  I don't want Lambda to keep running for a while and plus the maximum time for Lambda seems to be five minutes.  I looked at CloudWatch and AWS Config to see if I can capture snapshot events but had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct -- **there is no notification event** that signifies completion of an EBS Snapshot. Instead, you would need to check the status until the status changes to `completed`.

You are also correct that AWS Lambda functions can run for a **maximum of 5 minutes** and having a Lambda function waiting on an external process is not a good architecture.

Instead, you could **break-up the architecture**:

- Have your existing process trigger the EBS Snapshot(s) and then **push a message into an SQS queue**
- **Schedule a Lambda function** (eg every 5 minutes) to check the SQS queue. If a message exists:

  - Retrieve details about the instance and snapshot(s) from the message
  - **Check the status** of the snapshot(s)
  - If the status is `completed`, perform the next step in the process

The down-side is that the scheduled Lambda function will trigger even when there are no messages in the queue. The Lambda function will exit very quickly (cost: 100ms).

The alternative is to **run a `cron` script** on an Amazon EC2 instance (or on any computer connected to the Internet). A `t2.nano` instance is about 15.6c per day, which might be more expensive than a schedule Lambda function. If you already have an instance being used, then there would be no additional cost.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a new Event when Snapshots are completed in AWS Cloudwatch Events:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-cloud-watch-events.html